# Laravel update method not working correctly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here's my controller code:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $currency = Currency::find($id);

    $this->validate($request, [
        'cur_name' => 'required',
        'cur_price' => 'required|numeric',
        'cur_icon' => 'required|image|max:100',
        'cur_reserve' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);        

    $currency->cur_name = strip_tags($request->input('cur_name'));
    $currency->cur_price = $request->input('cur_price');

    // image
    $file = $request->file('cur_icon');

    if (isset($file)) {
        $filename = Str::lower(
            pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '-' . uniqid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension()
        );
        $destination = 'uploads/';
        $file->move($destination, $filename);
        $currency->cur_icon = $filename;
    }

    $currency->cur_reserve = $request->input('cur_reserve');
    $currency->slug = \Slug::make(strip_tags($request->input('cur_name')));
    dd($currency);
    $currency->save();

    return redirect('/admin/currency');
}
```

edit.blade.php (short):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/admin/currency/{{ $currency->id }}">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
...
</form>
```

routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::resource('currency', 'CurrencyController');
});
```

When i click on submit - i am not being redirected and nothing happens, just page reloads - that's all. Even if i modify data no changes are saved to database.

Comment: share your routes too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you aren't getting to `dd($currency);` before `$currency->save()`? then it may be the validator redirecting.  Try debugging with this in your view to check:

```
{{ count($errors) > 0 ? dd($errors->all()) : ''}}
```

Comment: `array:1 [▼
  0 => "The cur icon field is required."
]` You were right, that's validator. Could you tell, how can i separate validation rule if there's file input and when there's no file input in my case.

Comment: That's it.  In your validator change `'cur_icon' => 'required|image|max:100',` to `'cur_icon' => 'image',`  passing the `required` parameter looks for a field, not a file.  `image` is enough to require a file be present and also be an image.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you need to use url() method to get full url.

```
action="{{ url('/admin/currency/' . $currency->id) }}">
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Include something like:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
        'gender', 'phone' ,'isActive', 
        'photo','setup', 'address'
 ];
```

In your Model